# Is it possible to split a single Raid 1 array pair and mount a single disk?

Tags: mdadm, software-raid, raid1

I'm having a lot of problems with raid 1 arrays on my server.

Is it possible to split a raid 1 array into two seperate disks, and mount one, or either of them, as regular disks.

The raid 1 devices contain a single ext4 partition, if this is relevant to the question.

And the raid was created as a software raid with mdadm.

The OS is debian 10.

Comment: You want to remove the RAID layer? Or tell us about the _problems with raid 1 arrays_ and see if we can help you with that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mount a single hard disk that was part of RAID 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/300122/mount-a-single-hard-disk-that-was-part-of-raid-1)

Comment: @Freddy I don't think that's a duplicate. Your suggestion is about using half of a RAID 1 mirror with a missing disk, whereas this seems to be about removing the RAID 1 layer entirely and just mounting the resultant non-RAID filesystem

Comment: @roaima You are correct. I don't actually know what the issue is. mdadm fails to assemble the raid and there might not be a superblock on it, for some reason - although there should be. This is more a question the answer to which might help me diagnose the problem. Data isn't that important.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I anticipated doing, but this kind of does the job...

sudo mdadm --create --verbose --force /dev/md1 --level=1 --raid-devices=1 /dev/sdc

Note the "raid-devices=1", which requires the use of "--force" due to non-standard configuration.

This permits the user to inspect the contents of "/dev/sdc" if it was in a raid which broke (as mine did)